# Adding class objects in an array

Tags: php, arrays, class

Im a c# programmer and I'm learning arrays and classes in php. I'm trying to make an array list that contains objects of class document. At the end I want to print each object with its attributes. Here is my code.

Class Document

```
class Document {
  public $id;
  public $filename;
  public $filetype;
  public $filesize;
  public $datecreated;
  public $datemodified;

  public function __construct($id, $filename, $filetype, $filesize, $datecreated, $datemodified) {
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->filename = $filename;
    $this->filetype = $filetype;
    $this->filesize = $filesize;
    $this->datecreated = $datecreated;
    $this->datemodified = $datemodified;
  }
}
```

Thus is my code calling the class.

```
$documents = glob("C:/xampp/htdocs/researchPortal/document_repository/student/{*.doc,*.docx,*.png}", GLOB_BRACE);

$docArray = array();

//print each file name
foreach($documents as $doc)
{
$document = new Document(time(),basename($doc),substr($doc, -3),(filesize($doc)/1024),(filesize($doc)/1024)." KB",date("F d Y H:i:s.",filectime($doc)),date("F d Y H:i:s.",filemtime($doc)));
array_push($docArray,$document); 
}

foreach($docArray as $file) {

echo $file; //**ERROR ON THIS LINE**
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo:

```
array_push($docAray,$document);
```

should be

```
array_push($docArray,$document);
```

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled `$docArray` as `$docAray` on line 17.

Answer (score 0):

`$docAray` is a typo. `$docArray` is your array. See the missing r on the line where you made an error?